# react-native packager too long to start on windows

Tags: react-native

I have these numbers on packager time for my react-native project on a windows box

> [7:56:23 PM]    Crawling File System (104933ms)
>
> [7:56:23 PM]  Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
>
> [7:56:30 PM]    Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (7573ms)
>
> [7:56:30 PM]  Building in-memory fs for Assets
>
> [7:56:39 PM]    Building in-memory fs for Assets (8674ms)
>
> [7:56:39 PM]  Building Haste Map
>
> [7:56:42 PM]  Building (deprecated) Asset Map
>
> [7:56:43 PM]    Building (deprecated) Asset Map (1498ms)
>
> [7:56:43 PM]    Building Haste Map (4385ms)
>
> [7:56:43 PM]    Building Dependency Graph (125573ms)
>
> [7:57:52 PM] 
>   request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false
>
> [7:57:52 PM]  find dependencies
>
> [7:57:54 PM]    find dependencies (1545ms)
>
> [7:57:54 PM]  transform

This doesn't look normal. Is there anythig I can do to make it run a bit faster.

BTW, my dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.20.0",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^0.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: that used to happen to me, I re-installed my packages (deleteing node_modules folder and then `npm install`) and the packager became faster when starting.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried installing the gradle daemon?](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html#use-gradle-daemon)

> ## Use gradle daemon
>
> React Native Android use [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/) as a build system. We recommend to enable gradle daemon functionality which may result in up to 50% improvement in incremental build times for changes in java code. [Learn here how to enable it for your platform](https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html).

Comment: It is not actually the build, it is the packager.

Answer (score 0):

This can be normal for large projects.  Depending on which version of node you're using, since you're probably not using [watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman), the file watcher and dependency graph can take a long time to initialize.